# Access SQL - Allocate in a date range having only the start in each record

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am using Access 2010

I have two tables:

1. Prices table where I have the time when that price went into effect. When a price is updated I get another record with the new price and the time it went into effect. There is no key, this table is queried by two fields (contract, ProductCode).
2. Orders, where I have order date and price ordered.

What I want to do is check in the prices table which price was active at the time the order was placed. I was trying to get a table with all fields from Order PLUS the appropriate ContractedPrice and PriceValidFrom from table ContracPrices.

Example: [Sample solved database](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/82969825/Sample_solved.accdb) (with @carexcer contribution)

```
Orders
OrderNumber Contract    ProductCode OrderDate   PurchasePrice
Ord1    Cont1   AAA 07/05/2012  19,23
Ord1    Cont1   BBB 07/05/2012  5,66
Ord1    Cont1   CCC 07/05/2012  6,64

ContractPrices
Contract    ProductCode ContractedPrice PriceValidFrom
Cont1   AAA 21,14   11/02/2010 18:03:01
Cont1   AAA 21,84   08/10/2010 12:58:55
Cont1   AAA 22,06   22/06/2011 22:50:42
Cont1   AAA 1923,7  27/09/2011 14:17:08
Cont1   AAA 20      03/07/2012 12:40:36
Cont1   AAA 22,53   01/08/2012 21:37:26
Cont1   AAA 22,53   07/08/2012 19:33:29
Cont1   AAA 22,53   03/09/2012 18:26:38
Cont1   AAA 22,53   04/09/2012 16:20:09
Cont1   AAA 22,53   05/11/2012 18:53:18
Cont1   AAA 20      11/04/2013 15:28:49
Cont1   AAA 19,84   08/09/2013 19:00:10

DesiredResult
OrderNumber Contract    ProductCode OrderDate   PurchasePrice   ContractedPrice PriceValidFrom
Ord1    Cont1   AAA 07/05/2012  19,23   19,23   27/09/2011 14:17:08
```

Note that I am not restricted to order a product code from a single contract. Contract to ProductCode is many to many.

I would be open to VBA. I just do not know how to get about it without leaving the Access environment. I am new to databases.

I have brute force tested and saw that we were purchasing for more than the contracted price and so wanted to test the entire database.

I tried searching for this, but could not concisely express the problem.

Comment: 'Price Validity start date' is a field? And you haven't a 'Price Validity End Date'?

Comment: It came from SAP. This table was not meant for this, but it is the only place I could get this information. I think they did not expect the purchase price to be different from what the contract especified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this query will solve your problem:

```
SELECT
    t1.OrderNo, 
    t1.Contract,
    t1.ProductCode,
    MAX(t2.PriceValidityStartDate) as PriceValidityStartDate,
    MAX(t2.ContractPrice) AS PriceAtTime
FROM 
ORDERS t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
ContractPrices t2
ON t1.Contract = t2.Contract AND t1.ProductCode = t2.ProductCode 
WHERE 
    t1.OrderDate > t2.PriceValidityStartDate
GROUP BY 
    t1.OrderNo, 
    t1.Contract,
    t1.ProductCode
```

You have here the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/463ac/10) for test it.

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work. I edited my question to provide an example for which this code returned 22,53. I might be wrong, but I think this is not all that trivial. Thanks for the response

Comment: Ok, sorry. I change my answer, maybe it will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your support! It is getting the values wrong, but on the three points I tested the date was correct. I will try to work from that. I have uploaded screenshots of the points I tested: [Point 1](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/82969825/Temp%20-%20Fail%20example.png), [Point 2](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/82969825/Temp%20-%20Fails%20-%20Date%20works.png), [Point 3](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/82969825/Temp%20-%20Date%20works.png). I have also uploaded my database with your query in it to my question. I will update it if I get it right.

Comment: I discarded the PriceAtTime from your query and used the other values to join with my other tables and get where I wanted. This was very helpful!